# All top-level pages are using index.php as template

Tags: permalinks, templates, page-template, template-hierarchy

On my site, all top-level pages (i.e. *mydomain.com/example-page* as opposed to *mydomain.com/parent/example-page*) will only use index.php as their template. They won't use `page.php`, they won't use custom selected templates; only `index.php`

This only applies with I use `%postname%` as the permalink type.

I've tried re-saving the permalinks to flush them, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: It appears that if I change the permalink to: `mysite.com/1/%postname%` (rather than `/%postname%`), it works--and pages still actually use their default `/%postname%` format.

It appears that all *pages* are expected--by the system--to be posts. When the post is not found, it shows the index.php page. When I add the `/1/` (or any number/string) to the front of the permalink, it helps the system to know that if that isn't there, the pages are actually pages, and they work.

Why is that the case?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and your fix helped me a lot.

After I fixed the issue with your solution I figured out that I had used a permalink in one custom post type that caused the issue.

I used years / year and I think because wordpress uses something like this in its archive pages it broke the site.

Probably this helps you also.